# Java:best way to understand programming language

Tags: java

I already know the answer, but I am confused by the language.
  Assume there is a class `AirConditioner` that supports the following behaviors:

- turning the air conditioner on and off, and
- setting the desired temperature.

The following methods provide these behaviors:  `turnOn` and `turnOff`, which accept no arguments and return no value, and `setTemp`, which accepts an `int` argument and returns no value.

```
officeAC = new AirConditioner() ;

officeAC.turnOn() ;

officeAC.setTemp(69) ;
```

what does the following sentence mean?

The following methods provide these behaviors:  `turnOn` and `turnOff`, which accept no arguments and return no value.

Comment: That is why we have javadoc ...

Comment: What exactly don't you understand?  Those methods have no parameters (arguments), and they don't return values (void).  They invoke behavior which doesn't need information from outside the object and doesn't result in any calculated value other than updating the state of the object.

Comment: With Java, you're always confused by the language.

Comment: What your missing is knowledge of basic Object Oriented Principles. In this case the `turnOn` and `setTemp` methods are likely changing fields within the `officeAC` object. These fields can be accessed by the object in other methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`turnOn()` and `turnOff()` probably change the value of a field that depending on it's value, the `AirConditioner()` Object calling them is either on or off, and are probably implemented like this:

```
public class AirConditioner{

    private boolean isOn;
    private int temp;

    public AirConditioner(){
        this.isOn = false;
        temp = 0;
    }

    public void turnOn(){
        this.isOn = true;
    }

    public void turnOff(){
        this.isOn = false;
    }

}
```

the `setTemp()` sets a field holding the temperature, to the value in the parameter and is probably implemented like this:

```
public void setTem(int temp){
    this.temp = temp;
}
```

In your example you,

**1.** `officeAC = new AirConditioner() ;` **-->** create a new `Object` of type `AirConditioner` by calling its default constructor which probably looks something like the constructor in the code above.

**2.** `officeAC.turnOn() ;` **-->** change the field `isOn` of the calling `Object` officeAc to `true`

**3.** `officeAC.setTemp(69) ;` **-->** Set the field `temp` of the calling `Object` officeAc to `69`

Answer (score 0):

Methods on an object can do a number of things.  If you break them down semantically, there are a few basic options:

1. A method has access to the object's encapsulated state.  If it needs more information than is contained in that state, that information is required by the method in the form of parameters (or arguments).
2. A method can modify the object's encapsulated state.
3. A method can calculate a value which is not used by the object's encapsulated state.  If consuming code needs that value, the method returns that value.

   > The following methods provide these behaviors: turnOn and turnOff, which accept no arguments and return no value

Presumably the `turnOn` and `turnOff` methods:

- Require no external information, and therefore need no parameters.
- Do not result in a calculated value, and therefore return no value.
- Modify the object's internal state (not required, but certainly implied by their names).

Answer (score 0):

The sentence:

> The following methods provide these behaviors: turnOn and turnOff,
>   which accept no arguments and return no value

means what the object `officeAC` which is a of a class `AirConditioner` can do for you.

The methods `turnOn` and `turnOff` have no arguments means they end with `()` which accepts no input, but still does something when you call it (a behavior). The method `setTemp(69)` also defines some behavior and it also depends from the argument which in this case is `69`.

You can take for example a class dog:

```
class dog{

   void roll(int n){
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
         System.out.println("rolling ;P");
      }
   }

   String bark(){
      return "woof";
   }

}
```

The dog has two behaviors or methods `roll` and `bark`. Method `roll` will cause the dog to roll n times and `bark` will return a string `"woof"`.